# How do I prevent mouse wheel from incrementing numericupdown without over loading?

Tags: vb.net

How do I prevent mouse wheel from incrementing numericupdown without over loading?

I had previously inherited numericupdwon to overload the MouseWheel event with an empty event.  This worked for a while, but something happened when I switched to x64 that made the whole inherited class periodically show not found. Not sure because even if I switched back to x86 it was still a problem.

Comment: Windows 10 happened.  Big change, you don't like the new "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them" option.  Everybody else does.  Don't disappoint them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me..

```
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.MouseWheel

    Dim MW As HandledMouseEventArgs = CType(e, HandledMouseEventArgs)
    MW.Handled = True

End Sub
```

That HandledMouseEventArgs usage does look weird though.. but it works.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.handledmouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That worked for me with the mouse wheel, but not the keypress

Comment: Up/down.  I went back to check, it does work to prevent manual entry of numbers

Comment: OK so.. if you ONLY want the user to change it with the up down buttons on the control set the control to ReadOnly... It stops all imput except the up/down buttons.

Comment: Your code for KeyPress is equivilant to ReadOnly.  With ReadOnly, i can still use up/down keys and mouse wheel.

Comment: I got it to work for me a minute ago... now it wont.. ???
What did I do LOL

Comment: DUH.. Turn off InterceptArrowKeys

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a different solution, using the following code to prevent the increment

```
Private Sub nup_cores_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles nup_cores.MouseWheel
    nup_cores.Increment = 0
End Sub
```

And then change it back.  In the specific case of a numericupdown, the cursor blinking seems to trigger gotfocus.  The same principle could be applied with a short duration timer

```
Private Sub nup_cores_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nup_cores.GotFocus
    nup_cores.Increment = 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For C#:
For some reason the MouseWheel doesn't show up in the list of events from the GUI.  So I had to programmatically add the event in my form load. In the MouseWheel event I do something similar as the above selected answer (but a little different).

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numericUpDownX.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(handle_MouseWheel);
}

void handle_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
}
```